# What is the difference between occupants and affiliations?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, multiuserchat

Want to know how to add occupants in room.

Can we add occupants without adding affilitions?

Comment: I recommend reading XEP-0045.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are defined in MUC specification:

- [5.1 Roles](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#roles):

  > Roles are temporary in that they do not necessarily persist across a user's visits to the room and MAY change during the course of an occupant's visit to the room.
- [5.2 Affiliations](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#affil):

  > These affiliations are long-lived in that they persist across a user's visits to the room and are not affected by happenings in the room. In addition, there is no one-to-one mapping between these affiliations and an occupant's role within the room. Affiliations are granted, revoked, and maintained based on the user's bare JID, not the nick as with roles.